# Updating Drupal project using Composer fails

Tags: 8, updating, composer

I have site (which is originally installed also with composer) with drupal core version 8.7.2. I'm trying to update it to latest 8.7.8. When I do:

```
composer outdated "drupal/*"
```

I get the list of all outdate and for core I get row:

```
drupal/core                       8.7.2       8.7.8       Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites ..
```

But when I try:

```
composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies
```

I get:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

In composer.json core is added under require as (I just followed install docs - didn't change anything by hand):

```
"drupal/core": "^8.7.0",
```

That was suspicious to me so I tried replacing it with:

```
"drupal/core": "8.*",
```

But result was the same - nothing to update.

That message about phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects dependency is in green so I doubt that it causes this update to fail, but I'm not sure.

Why composer says that there's nothing to update?

**Update:**

Tried also:

```
composer prohibits drupal/core:8.7.8
```

and it says:

```
webflo/drupal-core-require-dev  8.7.2  requires  drupal/core (8.7.2)
```

And I really have inside composer.json:

```
"require-dev": {
    "webflo/drupal-core-require-dev": "^8.7.0"
},
```

Also tried:

```
composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies --no-dev
```

which removed dev dependencies, but also didn't update drupal core.
How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you can simply update core and all extensions in a single pass:

```
composer update
```

Only if this doesn't work, try to update core in a separate step by following the procedures described in the drupal composer project:

```
composer update drupal/core webflo/drupal-core-require-dev "symfony/*" --with-dependencies
```

See https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project

Comment: And if I can just add - if this also fails "composer prohibits" command can be used to find out what exactly is stopping the update so that dependency can also be added.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it. I had to add that "webflo/drupal-core-require-dev" to update command to be updates as well, because without that core couldn't be updated:

```
composer update drupal/core "webflo/drupal-core-require-dev" --with-dependencies
```

Saw that in "known issues" section. :/ 
It's really strange - what's the purpose of `--with-dependencies` when I have to add dependencies manually after all...